# How to force update of view titles after having changed the locale and restarted?

Tags: java, internationalization, osgi, eclipse-rcp

In a RCP application, I change the locale by programatically setting it in the `.ini` file and restarting the application.

The problem is that view titles, which are defined in `OSGI-INF/l10n` files referred from the plugin.xml file, aren't updated until I focus them.

For example after having switched from `EN` to `FR`, I have this :

[image]

It's only after I click on the second tab that I get this :

[image]

I can't reset the perspectives as they may have been changed by the user (view resized, removed or added). I've set `configurer.setSaveAndRestore(true);` in my `WorkbenchAdvisor.initialize` method to ensure the views layout is restored at launch.

Is there a way to programatically force an update of the views titles without losing the perspective configuration ?

I precise that I can't use the new Eclipse 4 (Juno) API.

Comment: Have you tried running eclipse with -clean?

Comment: @katsharp I tried adding `-clean` at the start of my `.ini` but it doesn't seem to do anything. Is this a supported option of all RCP application (i.e. not just the Eclipse IDE) ?

Comment: Yes it is - http://wiki.eclipse.org/RCP_FAQ

Comment: did you try a breakpoint in your view createPartControl, then debugging deep inside class hierarchy?

Comment: The instance of ViewPart isn't created until I click on the tab.

Answer (score 0):

As you are restoring perspective from previous session, it might be remembering part titles.
By default ViewPart doesnt do anything in `saveMemento()` method.
Override below methods are to debug the issue

```
 public void init(IViewSite site, IMemento memento) throws PartInitException 

   String getPartName()
```

Comment: The ViewPart instance isn't even created until I click on the tab.